# The image size exceeded limit size set but still can be uploaded, displayed and move to the folder

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload

I'm writing some code for upload and display image. But there is some error. I have set the image file limit. I try to run and upload image file which larger than the file limit I have set, suppose the image will not be uploaded, displayed  and move to folder "images/" but it still can be uploaded, displayed and moved to the folder. What should I do to solve this problem?  I really appreciate your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Upload image</title>
</head>

<?php
    $folder = "img/";
    $uploadOK = 1;

    if(isset($_POST['upload_img']) )
    {
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        //Check file size
        if($_FILES['image']['size'] > 500000)
        {
            $uploadOK = 0;
            echo "Sorry your file is too large. Please reupload.".'<br/>';
        }

        if($uploadOK = 1)
        {
            if($file_name)
            {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name , "img/$file_name");
            }

            if(is_dir($folder))
            {
                if($handle = opendir($folder))
                {
                    while(($file = readdir($handle)) != false)
                    {
                        if($file ==='.'|| $file === '..')
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<img src = "img/'.$file.'" width="150" height="150">'.'<br/>';        
                        }
                    }
                    closedir($handle);
                }
            }
        }   
    }

?>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="image">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="upload_img">
    </form>
</body>        
</html>
```

[Image of my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ih78.png)
The image attached is my result. The image of tulip is exceeding the file limit.

Comment: if($uploadOK = 1) is creating problem.Make if($uploadOK == 1)

Comment: Your if description if($uploadOK = 1) is the culprit, your stating that your passing the value of one to $uploadOK change it to $uploadOK == 1

Comment: Hi, i have tried that and it works but the image still being move to folder "images/". How can i stop it from moving to the folder ?

Comment: That is for another question, if my answer helped you for this question then kindly accept it or upvote it.

Comment: @XYZ  i have try and it works. thank you very much.

Comment: @L.Herrera i have try and it works. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if($uploadOK = 1)
```

to

```
if($uploadOK == 1)
```

Also, another layer of limting the filesize is also setting your `upload_max_filesize` setting in `php.ini`

Comment: Can i know what is php.ini ?

Comment: @NasrinYow, it's the PHP config. It's usually located on the PHP folder of your web server (e.g Apache).

Comment: @Ronald It doesn't matter about the `php.ini` file, because Nasrin Yow already have the file size limited.

Comment: @Antono, as I said, it's just an additional validation. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($uploadOK = 1)
```

Here you are assigning value 1 to uploadOk as = is assignment operator, so value of uploadOk will always be one hence always true.
what you need to do is use comparrison operator ie, == which will check if value of uploadOK is equal to 1 or not

so change,

```
if($uploadOK = 1)
```

to

```
if($uploadOK == 1)
```

Comment: @mahethekiller i have try and it works. thank you very much.